# Clear selected angular element

Tags: angular

If I select an angular element like this how can I empty it?

```
var svgContainer = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector(".svg-container");
```

Comment: What you want to be empty?

Comment: @LibinCJacob .svg-container

Comment: I think " svgContainer.empty();" is enough to clear all the content from the class  "svg-container"